# can i give my own id to a connected socket in nodejs

Tags: node.js

am trying to implement a multiuser communication app. I want to identify a user's socket with his id, so can i set socket's id to user' id like

```
socket.id=user.userId;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this, but use property that doesn't clash with Node.js or any other frameworks keys

```
socket.myappsuperuserid = user.userId;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..Later on how can i find this specific socket depending on myappsuperuserid and emit an event

Comment: use reverse lookup

var some_tbl[user.userId] = socket

Just remember to delete the socket from the table after its closed so you dont leak memory

Answer (score 3):

This may help you

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {    
    console.log("==== socket  ===");
    console.log(socket.id);
    socket.broadcast.emit('updatedid', socket.id);
});
```

you can save socket id in client side. When you want 1-1 message (private chat) use updated socket id. Some thing like this :

```
io.sockets.socket(id).emit('private message', msg, mysocket.id)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here

client side

```
var socket = io.connect();
     socket.on('connect', function () {
          console.log("client connection done.....");
          socket.emit('setUserId','random value');
});
```

On server side

```
io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
       socket.on('setUserId',function(uId){
             socket.userId = uId;
        });
});
```

This may help...

Comment: This is fine, thanks. But how can i get this socket based on uId, and send an event only to this socket out of a group

Answer (score 0):

In socket.io when a user connects, socket.io will generate a unique socket.id which basically is a random unique unguessable id. What i'd do is after i connect i call socket.join('userId'). basically here i assign a room to this socket with my userId. Then whenever i want to send something to this user, i'd do like this io.to(userId).emit('my message', 'hey there?').
Hope this help.